# Reducing repeated characters in a string while having a maximum number of repeated characters allowed

Tags: c

I have no idea how I would even begin to tackle this problem,

so for example
the string `"Hello Worlld"` should be
`"Helo World"` assuming that you can repeat a single word once,

hhhhiiii frieend - where you are allowed two repetitions of each letter per word
would be
hhii frieend

i'm not even sure where to begin I have to code this in c

EDIT:
function header

```
void ReduceString(char *word, int Maximum)
```

EDIT2:
not case sensitive,
only limited to stdio.h and string.h
there is a limit for maximum number of consecutive characters, all consecutive characters exceeding this maximum number
should be eliminated.

Comment: "repeat a single word once". Don't you mean letter? Also, do you mean consecutive repetitions?

Comment: Use Run Length Encode, clip the number of repeat and decode it.

Comment: yes letter, sorry i do i'm limited to the standard library for this task

Comment: And consecutive only? (Easier).

Comment: yup it is the maximum number of consecutive characters

Comment: sorry i wasn't very clear

Comment: What does "limited to the standard library" mean? Can't you even add or subtract some numbers without using standard library?

Comment: i only have access to stdio.h and string.h, sorry i'm fairly new to programming

Comment: @sid : Remember to edit your question to update it with all information from comments

Comment: And lastly, is this case sensitive? And if not, which letter gets removed?

Comment: So `malloc` is banned for example?

Comment: no it is not case sensitive, the letter which gets removed would be the ones that occur after the first appearance of the letter e.g hii would become hi so the 3rd character would be deleted

Comment: Now be an angel and edit your question with all these clarifications. Else I think it will be downvoted and perhaps even closed.

Comment: no mike malloc is not banned but we haven't been taught how to pre-allocate using malloc

Comment: we are not here to do your homework for you.  We are here to help with 'it does not compile' and 'it does not output the desired output'.   So, post your code and a explanation of what is not working correctly.

Comment: a few questions:   is the passed in char pointer pointing to something on the stack/heap or something in a literal?   do you want to edit the passed in char string 'in place' or is the code going to simply call printf() with the result?

Comment: yeah the edit passed in the char string should be in place, i see i will take note for next time thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
void x(char *s, int n)
{
    char *cp= s;
    int i, j;

    while (*cp) {
        i= 1;
        while (*(cp+i) && ((*(cp+i))&~32)==((*cp)&~32)) i++;    // count character repeat
        for (j=0; j<n && j<i; j++)              // repeat at most max repeat (n)
            *s++ = *(cp+j);
        cp += i;
    }
    *s= '\0';
}
```

EDIT: added max repeat (n)

EDIT: made case insensitive: `&~32` removes the lower case bit in ASCII (this will get me the obfuscated C price).

Comment: this answer is case sensitive.  Therefore, it does not meet the requirements as stated by the OP

Answer (score 0):

Count continuous characters, and output characters if the number of repetitions isn't exceeding the limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* this function make alphabet lower and make it not case sensitive */
/* note that tolower, which is in ctype.h, is not available here */
char normalizeAlphabet(char in)
{
    static const char* upperAlphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static const char* lowerAlphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int index = -1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; upperAlphabets[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (in == upperAlphabets[i])
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return lowerAlphabets[index];
    }
    else
    {
        return in;
    }
}

void ReduceString(char *word, int Maximum)
{
    char *out = word;
    int currentRepetition = 0;
    int doNotOutput = 0;
    char currentChar = '\0';
    char normalizedChar;
    while (*word != '\0')
    {
        normalizedChar = normalizeAlphabet(*word);
        if (normalizedChar == currentChar)
        {
            /* continuous same characters */
            if (currentRepetition < Maximum)
            {
                currentRepetition++;
            }
            else
            {
                doNotOutput = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* hit to another character */
            currentChar = normalizedChar;
            currentRepetition = 1;
            doNotOutput = 0;
            if (Maximum < currentRepetition) doNotOutput = 1;
        }
        if (!doNotOutput)
        {
            /* if repetition is not touching the limit, output the character */
            *out = *word;
            out++;
        }
        word++;
    }
    *out = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[1024];
    char buf[1024];
    while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin))
    {
        int i;
        printf("input : %s", input);
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            strcpy(buf, input);
            ReduceString(buf, i);
            printf("reduced Maximum = %d : %s", i, buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i can't quite follow the reducestring function though it would be very helpful if somebody could explain/annotate it